# Reloading an Element After Data Is Loaded in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am building an app with [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org). In my app, a user logs into the app. When they login, I am trying to show their orders. They can then choose an order and view the order details. To display the orders, I have a custom element that looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="customer-orders">
    <template>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Welcome. You have ordered:</h3>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ orders }}" as="order">              
            <div on-click="orderSelected">
              <span>[[ order.total ]]</span>
              <span>[[ order.description ]]</span>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'customer-orders',
            properties: {
              orders: {
                type: Array,
                notify: true,
                value: function() {
                  return [];
                }
              }
            },

            orderSelected:function() {
              /* What goes here? */
            }
        });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

How do I "tell" `customer-orders` to reload its data? My app is structured kind of like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <user-account></user-account>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <customer-orders></customer-orders>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <customer-order></customer-order>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can imagine, when a user logs in, I need to refresh the customer-orders data. Then, when a user selects an order, I need to grab the order details. There are two scenarios where I need to "refresh" the control's data.

My problem is, the elements are on the screen and the user may not have logged in or, they may not have chosen an order. For that reason, I can't use the `created`, `ready` or `attached` callbacks. Its like I need to listen for when the user logs in or chooses an order. Then, either a) broadcast a message throughout the app that somehow the elements listen to or b) Specifically tell `custom-order` to refresh. However, I'm not sure how, or if there is a way to do either of those.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I do not see data loading for {{orders}}. Once the user sign in is complete, you have to populate the `orders` array. Then dom-repeat will update itself. You also might want to wrap the h3 tag with dom-if and show it only if orders array has atleast one item.

Comment: I am trying to populate the `orders` array. However, I cannot populate the `orders` array until after the user logs in. That's why I need a way to tell the control to refresh its data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom event fired from the host for reloading your customers-orders when login is successfully, For viewing the customer order you need to grab the orders selected by the customer.
 Add another Object for storing selecting orders let's says `selectedOrders` and using  array-selector you can  ensures path linkage when selecting specific items and store orders in `selectedOrders`. I have scaffold something here , though I did not test it can gives you something that might help you. Especially

1. [using array-selector for storing selecting elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#array-selector)
2. [fire an event from the host using custom event function :
   `fire`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#custom-events)

## customer-orders elements

```js
<dom-module id="customer-orders">
    <template>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Welcome. You have ordered:</h3>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ orders }}" as="order" id="ordersList">              
            <div on-click="orderSelected">
              <span>[[ order.total ]]</span>
              <span>[[ order.description ]]</span>          
            </div>
            </template> //close the dom-repeat template
            <array-selector id="orderSelector" items="{{orders}}}" selected="{{selectedOrders}}" multi toggle></array-selector>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'customer-orders',
            properties: {
              orders: {
                type: Array,
                notify: true,
                value: function() {
                  return [];
                }
              },
              selectedOrder:Object
                
            },

            orderSelected:function(e) {
               var item=this.$.ordersList.itemForElement(e.target);
              this.$.orderSelector.select(item);
              //update the selected orders 
              this.set('selectedOrder',item);
              // fire app onOrderChange event               
              this.fire('onOrderChange',item);
               
              
            }
        });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

the `customer-order` element should have a property data that fetch selected orders data from the `selectedOrder` in `customers-orders`.

## customer-order

```js
<dom-module id="customer-order">
    <template>
      
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'customer-order',
            properties: {
             data: {
                type: Object,
                notify: true
                
              }
            }
        });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

## Now your app will look like

```js
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <user-account></user-account>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <customer-orders ></customer-orders>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <customer-order id="Custorder"></customer-order>
  </div>
</div>
  

    <script>
       
  document.querySelector('customer-orders').addEventListener('OrderChange', function (e){
        this.Custorder.data=e.detail.item;
    })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the user login is complete you should run `generateRequst()` on the iron-ajax elemement which gets `orders` from the backend. You can do it in many different ways. Below is a reference design.  You can modify it per your needs.

Your parent element design could be something like below:

```
<custom-orders orders={{orders}}></custom-orders>
<iron-ajax url="user/login" on-response="getOrders"></iron-ajax>
<iron-ajax id="userOrders" url="get/orders" last-response="{{orders}}"></iron-ajax>
<script>
  properties: {
    orders: Object,
  },
  getOrders: function() {
    this.$.userOrders.generateRequest();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I'm not using iron. I've updated my question so you can see the structure of the app.