# How to communicate the changes in dom-repeat across the iron-pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

We are planning with the below architecture..

We have 3 iron pages, say 1,2,3. These are put into landingpage.html.
We traverse from page 1, to 2 through a next button, similarly can traverse back from 2 to 1 through previous button.

When we load landingpage.html, in ready function I will get the data that should be populated/ traversed, say I store in object dataset

Now on page 1, [iron page] , I do a dom-repeat and push each item , after putting the dataset into items. Each row I call through dom-repeat is a component.
I have some User Input and drop down in those components. So each sub- dataset broken from dataset, makes some edition.

Now I used {{double binding}} [checked with single binding also], to send the data, but the changes were not reflecting to the main dataset.
So I used a fire event where I propagate the changes to the parent html(s). I handled those fires and updated the main dataset.

But I see that the same dataset which I bound to the iron-pages 2 and 3 is not getting the changed data.  It is still holding the data that I got on ready() of landingpage.html.

I tried a no of trials to populate the current data to iron-pages 2 and 3.  But didn’t click.
a)  Tried to use restamp, restamp=true
b)  Used this.$.recall.render();[where I put id=recall in a wrapper dom-if whose condition is always true]
c)  Even I tried to put a condition which will fail for all screens except the first one, I set a flag what will be TRUE only when I trigger an event on click for NEXT to route to 2nd page. But still I don’t find any effect.
d)  I tried to wrap the child-dom-calling tags with a div and an ID. this.$.ID.render(); But I find error, can’t understand function render.

What I notice that the pages got rendered on the first go only, i.e all 3 iron pages are rendered on pass-1. And I want to render / reload that div.

Could you please find me a way/process so that I can publish the updated values in iron-page 1 to iron-page 2 and 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it'll be more helpful if you add code instead if writing such a long query

Comment: You need to post the code so we can comment.  One immediate thought, but which I can't check, is when you are updating the data you are doing so directly and not `this.set('path.to.item', value)`. If you don't do it this way, the data will update but the screen won't

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late reply, I just tried out like using this.$.divname.setdataset(this.dataset); and not sending the dataset as argument. It solves the problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313043/reloading-an-element-after-data-is-loaded-in-polymer

yet I would like to post the code, but I need to do some modulations as that is Prod Code, which cant be shared on public.