# How to refresh components

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

First of all, sorry if my question is too silly, I'm still new with Polymer 2.

I'm facing a little issue. I've created a custom component, where I load some dynamic data via xhr. 
Everything seems to work correctly, but I've noticed that when I leave and come back to this view, the component has not changed, even if it raises all the xhr to get new data.

I'm wondering if the issue is that the data is updated, but the DOM is still the same.

Is it possible to force the system to "reload" the component each time I visit the page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to finde first in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/33371129/4921471

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I've already tried that. I guess the issue is with that the DOM is not being modified, in my case all new data is already loaded

Comment: put a demo, and will help you better

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom "tree view component".

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-collapse-item/paper-collapse-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/vaadin-icons/vaadin-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-location/iron-location.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../portal_components/portal-measurement-units/portal-measurement-units.html">

<dom-module id="portal-tree-view">
     <template>
     <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
     <style>
     :host {
          display: block;
     }
     .icon
     {
          margin-right: 24px;
          --iron-icon-height: 34px;
          --iron-icon-width: 34px;
          color: var(--disabled-text-color);
     }

     .icon-small
     {
          margin-right: 24px;
          --iron-icon-height: 20px;
          --iron-icon-width: 20px;
          color: var(--disabled-text-color);
     }

     .icon-big
     {
          margin-right: 24px;
          --iron-icon-height: 40px;
          --iron-icon-width: 40px;
          color: var(--disabled-text-color);
     }

     .alert {
          color: orange;
     }
     .emergency {
          color: red;
     }
     </style>
     <template is="dom-if" if=[[!loading]]>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items={{tree}}>
               <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.deploy]]">
                    <paper-collapse-item icon="icons:label" header="[[item.name]]" id="collapseitem" >
                         <portal-tree-view assets=[[item.children]] tasks=[[tasks]] results=[[results]] network=[[network]]></portal-tree-view>
                    </paper-collapse-item>
               </template>
               <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.mp]]">
                    <span style= "font-size: var(--paper-font-subhead_-_font-size); margin-left: 15px;">
                         <iron-icon class="icon" icon="label-outline"></iron-icon>
                         <iron-icon class="icon-big" style="color: black; float: right; margin-top: 40px" icon="vaadin:info-circle-o" on-click="goDetail"></iron-icon>
                          [[item.name]] <br/>
                          <span style="margin-left: 96px">
                              <iron-icon class="icon-small" style="color: [[item.lastacq_status]]" icon="vaadin:spark-line"></iron-icon>
                              <span style="color: [[checkLastAcqStatus(item)]]">[[getLastAcq(item)]]</span>
                         </span><br/>
                          <span style="margin-left: 86px">
                               Speed: <span style="color: [[checkSpeedStatus(item)]]">[[checkSpeed(item)]] </span>
                          </span><br/>
                          <span style="margin-left: 86px">
                               Acceleration: <span style="color: [[checkAccStatus(item)]]">[[checkAcc(item)]]</span>
                          </span><br/>
                          <span style="margin-left: 86px">
                               Temperature: <span style="color: [[checkTempStatus(item)]]">[[checkTemp(item)]]</item>
                          </span><br/>
                    </span><br/>
               </template>
               <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.transmitter]]">
                    <span style= "font-size: var(--paper-font-subhead_-_font-size); margin-left: 15px;">
                         <iron-icon class="icon" icon="label-outline"></iron-icon>
                          [[item.name]]<br/>
                    </span>
                    <span style="margin-left: 96px">
                         <iron-icon class="icon-small" style="color: [[item.latcom_status]]" icon="settings-input-antenna"></iron-icon>
                         <span style="color: [[checkLastComStatus(item)]]">[[getLastCom(item)]]</span>
                    </span><br/>
               </template>
               <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.endpoint]]">
                    <span style= "font-size: var(--paper-font-subhead_-_font-size); margin-left: 15px;">
                         <iron-icon class="icon" icon="label-outline"></iron-icon>
                          [[item.name]]<br/>
                    </span>
               </template>
          </template>
     </template>
     <template is="dom-if" if=[[loading]]>
          <div class="center-center layout horizontal">
               <img src="portal_components/portal-tree-view/loading.gif" />
          </div>
     </template>
     <portal-lite-global-variables id="GLOBALS"></portal-lite-global-variables>
     <portal-measurement-units id="UNITS"></portal-measurement-units>
     <iron-location id="location"></iron-location>

</template>

<script>
/**
* `portal-tree-view`
*
*
* @customElement
* @polymer
* @demo demo/index.html
*/
class portalTreeView extends Polymer.Element {
     static get is() { return 'portal-tree-view'; }
     static get properties() {
          return {
               assets: {
                    type: Array,
                    notify: true,
               },
               tasks: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true,
               },
               results: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true,
               },
               network: {
                    type: Array,
                    notify: true
               },
               tree: {
                    type: Array,
                    notify: true
               },
               trigger: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    observer: '_trigger'
               }
          };
     }
     static get observers() {
          return [
               'fullAssets(tasks, results)'
          ]
     }

     _trigger()
     {
          if (this.trigger)
          {
               this.ready();
               console.log("trigger")
               this.fullAssets();
          }
     }

     toFixed(value, precision) {
        return Number(value).toFixed(precision);
      }
     goDetail(event)
     {
          var item = event.model.item;
          this.$.location.path="portal-lite-asset-details/"+item._id;

     }
     checkLastComStatus(item)
     {
          if (this.network[item.mac] !== undefined)
          {
               var current = this.$.GLOBALS.getUTCTimeStamp(new Date());
               if (current < this.$.GLOBALS.getUTCTimeStamp(new Date(this.network[item.mac].last_com)) + 54000)
                    return 'orange';
               else if (current > this.$.GLOBALS.getUTCTimeStamp(new Date(this.network[item.mac].last_com)) + 54000)
                    return 'red';
          }

     }
     getLastAcq(item)
     {
          if (this.results[item._id] !== undefined)
               return new Date(this.results[item._id].acqend).toLocaleDateString() + " " + new Date(this.results[item._id].acqend).toLocaleTimeString();
     }
     getLastCom(item)
     {
          if (this.network[item.mac] !== undefined)
               return new Date(this.network[item.mac].last_com).toLocaleDateString() + " " + new Date(this.network[item.mac].last_com).toLocaleTimeString();
     }
     checkLastAcqStatus(item)
     {
          if (this.tasks[item._id] !== undefined)
               return this.$.GLOBALS.checkTask(this.tasks[item._id], this.results[item._id]);
     }
     checkSpeed(item)
     {
          if (this.results[item._id] !== undefined)
          {
               if (this.results[item._id].globals.vib !== undefined &&
                    this.results[item._id].globals.vib.v !== undefined)
                    {
                         var aux = this.$.UNITS.speed(this.results[item._id].globals.vib.v[0]);
                         return aux.value.toFixed(2) + " " + aux.desc;
                    }
          }
     }

     checkSpeedStatus(item)
     {
          if (this.results[item._id] !== undefined)
          {

               if (this.results[item._id].globals.vib !== undefined &&
                    this.results[item._id].globals.vib.v !== undefined)
               {
                    if (this.results[item._id].globals.vib.v[1] == 1) return "orange";
                    else if (this.results[item._id].globals.vib.v[1] == 2) return "red";
               }
          }
     }

     checkAccStatus(item)
     {
          if (this.results[item._id] !== undefined)
          {
               if (this.results[item._id].globals.vib !== undefined &&
                    this.results[item._id].globals.vib.a !== undefined)
               {
                    if (this.results[item._id].globals.vib.a[1] == 1) return "orange";
                    else if (this.results[item._id].globals.vib.a[1] == 2) return "red";
               }
          }
     }

     checkTempStatus(item)
     {
          if (this.results[item._id] !== undefined)
               if (this.results[item._id].globals.temp !== undefined &&
                    this.results[item._id].globals.temp !== null)
               {
                    if (this.results[item._id].globals.temp[1] == 1) return "orange";
                    else if (this.results[item._id].globals.temp[1] == 2) return "red";
               }
     }
     checkAcc(item)
     {
          if (this.results[item._id] !== undefined)
          {

               if (this.results[item._id].globals.vib !== undefined &&
                    this.results[item._id].globals.vib.a !== undefined)
               {
                    var aux = this.$.UNITS.g(this.results[item._id].globals.vib.a[0]);
                    return aux.value.toFixed(2) + " " + aux.desc;
               }
          }
     }

     checkTemp(item)
     {
          if (this.results[item._id] !== undefined)
          {
               if (this.results[item._id].globals.temp !== undefined &&
                    this.results[item._id].globals.temp !== null)
               {
                    var aux = this.$.UNITS.temp(this.results[item._id].globals.temp[0]);
                    return aux.value.toFixed(1) + " " + aux.desc;
               }
          }
     }

     fullAssets()
     {
          if (this.assets !== undefined && this.network !== undefined)
          {
               this.loading = false;
               this.assets.sort(function(d1,d2)
               {
                    if (d1.children.length > 0) return -1;
                    return 1;
               });
               for (var i = 0; i < this.assets.length; i++)
               {
                    this.assets[i].endpoint = false;
                    this.assets[i].mp = false;
                    this.assets[i].transmitter = false;
                    if (this.assets[i].children.length === 0)
                         this.assets[i].endpoint = true;
                    if (this.assets[i].t == 33554435)
                    {
                         this.assets[i].endpoint = false;
                         this.assets[i].transmitter = true;
                         this.assets[i].mac = this.assets[i].optionals.mac.toUpperCase();
                    }
                    if (this.assets[i].t == 16777218)
                    {
                         this.assets[i].endpoint = false;
                         this.assets[i].mp = true
                    }
                    this.assets[i].deploy = !this.assets[i].mp && !this.assets[i].endpoint && !this.assets[i].transmitter;
               }
               this.notifyPath('tree', this.assets);
          }
     }
     constructor()
     {
          super();
          this.loading = true;
          this.queue_results = 0;
     }
     ready()
     {
          super.ready();
     }
}
window.customElements.define(portalTreeView.is, portalTreeView);
</script>
</dom-module>
```

On this.$.UNITS I have a set of functions to make a conversion of values (Metric, Imperial, etc...).

The function checkSpeed(item) is executed each time I show the view.
Via console.log I can check that the value returned is always correct, but when leaving, I change the unity (from metric to imperial, for instance), and when I'm back again the view in the component remains in the old unities (even if the console.log in the function returns the correct value).

Hope it's useful.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

Finally found out the solution here: https://easyusedev.wordpress.com/2015/11/06/dynamically-loading-polymer-elements-on-the-fly/

In order to be sure that the component is refresed each time I call the view, create the component manually when everything's ready to load the component:

```
var tree = document.createElement('portal-tree-view');
```

And, when leaving, I remove it:

```
var element = this.$.container.querySelector("portal-tree-view");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

En cualquier caso, muchas gracias por tu tiempo Álvaro.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are doing `this.notifyPath('tree', this.assets);` in `fullAssets()`, but I think the syntax is not correct.

From the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notify-path):

> When calling notifyPath, **you need to use the exact path that changed**.
>   For example, calling this.notifyPath('profile') doesn't pick up a
>   change to profile.name because the profile object itself hasn't
>   changed.

So try to do this:

```
this.notifyPath('tree.property_you_want_to_be_changed');
```

Or maybe would be better to you to use [MutableData mixin](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system#mutable-data). This mixin allows the array to be updated and the UI be notified simpley doing

```
this.notifyPath('tree');
```

Comment: Thanks Arnau, I didn't notice that! I will keep it in mind for the coming developments. Thanks a lot!